# No property index found for type User

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm trying to use ElasticSearch with MySQL in the same project.
I defined two repositories in different project but I always get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.owish.services.UserServices com.owish.controllers.UserController.userServices; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServices': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.owish.repositories.search.UserSearchRepo com.owish.services.UserServices.userSearchRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property index found for type User!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.owish.services.AppServices.main(AppServices.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.owish.services.UserServices com.owish.controllers.UserController.userServices; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServices': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.owish.repositories.search.UserSearchRepo com.owish.services.UserServices.userSearchRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property index found for type User!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServices': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.owish.repositories.search.UserSearchRepo com.owish.services.UserServices.userSearchRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property index found for type User!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.owish.repositories.search.UserSearchRepo com.owish.services.UserServices.userSearchRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property index found for type User!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property index found for type User!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property index found for type User!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:84)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:62)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:100)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:211)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 38 more
```

When I was just using the `JpaRepository` I had no problem.
I got that issue only when I added another repository that extends `ElasticsearchRepository`.
the interface definition of JPA and Elastic search were defined in different packages.
I'm using elastic search 2.2.1 with Spring data elasticsearch 1.3.4
I think it's a configuration issue.
below is the application config that I'm using. Would you tell me if I'm missing something:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.owish." />

<elasticsearch:node-client id="client" local="true" />
<elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.owish.repositories.search" />
<elasticsearch:transport-client id="client"
    cluster-nodes="localhost:9200,someip:9200" />


<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/owish"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"></property>
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"></property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.owish.model" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpa.sample"></property>
</bean>
<!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.owish.repositories" />
<!-- Enable annotation driven transaction management -->
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

My user entity was declared like this:

```
@Entity
@Table (name ="user")
@Document(indexName = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@Column (name = "id") 
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
@Column (name = "username", nullable = false)
private String username;
@Column (name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;
```

and my ElasticSearch repo was defined like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserSearchRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, Long> {
User findByUsername(String username);
List<User> findAllByOrderById ();
}
```

and my JPA repo

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Add the `userSearchRepo` bean class...

Comment: @AliDehghani where should I add it?

Comment: Add the corresponding class to `userSearchRepo` in your question, in order to make your problem more clear.

Comment: @AliDehghani done :)

Comment: `findAllByOrderById` is supposed to find all the users and order them by id?

Comment: @AliDehghani yes, but the problem occurs even without those two methode declared in the interface `findAllByOrderById` and `findByUsername`

Comment: Just for testing sake, move your search repositories to, say,  `com.owish.search` package and use `<elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.owish.search" />` instead.

Comment: @AliDehghani Same issue, it was in fact the first config, then I found that JPA and ElasticSearch can't be set in the same package as they can't be handled by Spring

Comment: @AliDehghani thank you I got another error now :) I shoud define the `elasticsearchTemplate` do you have any idea?

Comment: @AliDehghani `Cannot resolve reference to bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property 'elasticsearchOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'elasticsearchTemplate' is defined`

Comment: Try to remove the `<elasticsearch:transport-client id="client"
    cluster-nodes="localhost:9200,someip:9200" />`

Comment: Also you can register an `ElasticSearchTemplate` by adding `<bean id="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="client" />
    </bean>`

Comment: @AliDehghani Thank you So much for your Help :) I know it that was messing a lot of config. now I have this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/settings/ImmutableSettings$Builder`

Comment: Probably, it's a version conflict. It's better to ask another question and add your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`  to that question. I'm so sleepy..Good luck

Comment: @AliDehghani Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ElasticsearchRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/ElasticsearchRepository.html#index-S-) has a method named `index`, there is no harm in that, but since you did put your *ElasticSearch Repositories* in `com.owish.repositories.search` package, it would be scanned by *Spring Data JPA Scanner*:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.owish.repositories" />
```

So, Spring Data JPA would try to proxy your `UserSearchRepo` and couldn't find any property named `index` in the `User` class, hence the error:

> No property index found for type User!

Anyway, if you move your ElasticSearch Repositories away from `com.owish.repositories` package and its sub-packages, you would be fine. For example, you can move your ElasticSearch Repositories to `com.owish.search` and also:

```
<elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.owish.search" />
```

And a word of advice, try to define *one configuration for each architectural aspect of your application, e.g. one for data, one for web, one for security, and put only related configurations in each of them*. I did not get the role of this component scanner in your *Data Access Related* configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.owish." />
```

Maybe it's necessary in order to make your application up and running but i seriously doubt the fact that this belongs to the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the error carefully you will understand its cause

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.owish.services.UserServices com.owish.controllers.UserController.userServices; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServices': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.owish.repositories.search.UserSearchRepo com.owish.services.UserServices.userSearchRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property index found for type User!

So last line of it says No property index for type User,

that means you have a class named User and in that there is a property with which you are mapping table named index.

A similar issue [spring data jpa @Entity property not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304128/spring-data-jpa-entity-property-not-found-exception)

Comment: I don't think that there is nothing with the mapping, please check my last update :) I'm sure that's a config issue.