# Elasticsearch config with Repository end up with Exception on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have some trouble to get the right config for jpa repository for elasticsearch.
The configuration is for aws elasticsearch

```
@Component
public class AmazonElasticSearchConnector implements AmazonElasticSearchClient {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.endpoint}")
    private String elasticSearchEndpoint;

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient createClient() {
        return createClient(elasticSearchEndpoint);
    }
}
```

and then i have another config

```
@Configuration
public class ESConfig {
  @Autowired
  private RestHighLevelClient client;
  @Bean
  public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
    return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client);
  }

}
```

Here my Entity

```
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "item")
public class SupplierItemFilterResponseEntity {

  @ElementCollection
  private List<String> searchCollect;
  @Id
  private int id;

....
```

and my nested Entity

```
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "item")
public class TechnologyFilterEntity {

  public int getTechnologyID() {
    return technologyID;
  }

  public void setTechnologyID(int technologyID) {
    this.technologyID = technologyID;
  }
....
```

and I have a repository

```
public interface SupplierItemFilterESRepository extends
    ElasticsearchRepository<SupplierItemFilterResponseEntity, Integer> {
}
```

And then the service that encountered an error

```
  @Autowired
  private RestHighLevelClient client;
  @Autowired
  private SupplierItemFilterESRepository supplierItemFilterESRepository;

  public Page<SupplierItemFilterResponseEntity> getSupplierWithGivenFiltersPagination(Pageable pageable) {
    return supplierItemFilterESRepository.findAll(pageable);
  }

....
```

and the Error i get is following

```
No property indexWithoutRefresh found for type SupplierItemFilterResponseEntity!
```

Im on it for 2 days now, and my expertise is over. Maybe someone has the same problem.

Cheers and thank you if you can help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No property index found for type User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252099/no-property-index-found-for-type-user)

Comment: Yes i found this article but I have done this configuration also and it doesnt work